# Converting "for" loop to "while" loop

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

I´m currently working on my semester work and this is a piece of my code. As you can see there is a for loop with some if statements where I am working with a structure. I was thinking of converting this for loop onto a while loop but I´m not quite sure how. Maybe someone may give me a hint?

```
for(X = 1; X <= 100; X++) 
        {
          if(structure[X].number == -1)
          {
            structure[X].number = number;
            structure[X].first_info = position;
            structure[X].second_info = position;
            break;
          }
          if(structure[X].number == number)
          {
            if(structure[X].first_info == -1) 
              structure[X].first_info = position;
              structure[X].second_info = position;
              break;
          }
        }
```

Comment: what is the reason you want to convert to `while` loop?

Comment: You have an indentation problem after the third if, or you’re missing some braces.

Comment: A for loop is much better than a while loop because it keeps all the loop control information on a single line.

Comment: And unless `structure` is an array of dimension 101 or more, `X<100` should be the correct condition for the `while`/`for` loop

Answer (score 2):

All basic loops have three components:

- an initializer (an initial value assigned to a variable)
- a condition (the value we are checking for to stay in the loop)
- a modifier (something that modifies our variable)

With a for loop you notice all three of those here:

```
for(X = 1; X <= 100; X++)
```

The first component in the parentheses is an initializer (X=1), the next component is the condition (X <= 100), and the last component is the modifier (X++).

We can use the exact same components with a while loop. We just place them differently:

```
int x = 1; //our intializer
while (x <= 100){ //our condition
      if(structure[X].number == -1)
      {
        structure[X].number = number;
        structure[X].first_info = position;
        structure[X].second_info = position;
        break;
      }
      if(structure[X].number == number)
      {
          if(structure[X].first_info == -1){
              structure[X].first_info = position;
          }
          structure[X].second_info = position;
          break;
      }
      x++; //our modifier
   }
```

With that said, arrays in C always start at index 0. I kept your code the same as you had it, but generally whether you are using a for loop or while loop you will want to change your initializer and condition as follows:

- your initializer should likely be x = 0 (not x = 1)
- your condition should likely be either x < 100 or x <= 99 (not x <= 100)

This is because an array of 100 items will have indexes 0 to 99.

Two more points:

When counting through an indexed array like this the code is usually easier to read as a for loop rather than a while loop. Is there a reason that you were wanting to use a while loop instead?

Based on your indentation it was unclear what should be included in the last if clause. I have added braces to your last if clause to make it easier to read, but maybe other lines should have been included in the braces as well?

Answer (score 2):

Converting the `for` loop to a `while` loop is easy, but the `for` loop is a much safer construct as it groups the initialization, test and increment of the index variable in one clear place.

Incidentally, your code is misindented, and the nested `if` statements may be inconsistent:

```
      if(structure[X].number == number)
      {
        if(structure[X].first_info == -1) 
          structure[X].first_info = position;
          structure[X].second_info = position;
          break;
      }
```

When properly reformated, it becomes:

```
      if (structure[X].number == number) {
          if (structure[X].first_info == -1) 
              structure[X].first_info = position;
          structure[X].second_info = position;
          break;
      }
```

Is this what you intended?  Be more careful with indentation, it helps avoid silly mistakes.

Here is the converted code, but be aware that contrary to a `for` statement, a `continue` statement would by-pass the `X++` update expression.  Also worth noting is the surprising use of a 1 based index value for `X`. Index values are 0 based in C and array size can be checked with a `<` comparison instead of `<=`.

```
X = 1;
while (X <= 100) {
    if (structure[X].number == -1) {
        structure[X].number = number;
        structure[X].first_info = position;
        structure[X].second_info = position;
        break;
    }
    if (structure[X].number == number) {
        if (structure[X].first_info == -1) 
            structure[X].first_info = position;
        structure[X].second_info = position;
        break;
    }
    X++;
}
```

If `structure` has 100 elements, the code must be changed to:

```
X = 0;
while (X < 100) {
    if (structure[X].number == -1) {
        structure[X].number = number;
        structure[X].first_info = position;
        structure[X].second_info = position;
        break;
    }
    if (structure[X].number == number) {
        if (structure[X].first_info == -1) 
            structure[X].first_info = position;
        structure[X].second_info = position;
        break;
    }
    X++;
}
```

Comment: By far the best answer here, UV

Comment: It is NOT a "a much safer construct". It depends on the situation.

Comment: @chqrlie, ah..I see. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to convert to `while` loop. But I would suggest to search and understand the `loop` structures yourself.

```
X=0;   /* for arrays indexing always starts at 0 */
while(X<100)
{
      if(structure[X].number == -1)
      {
        structure[X].number = number;
        structure[X].first_info = position;
        structure[X].second_info = position;
        break;
      }
      if(structure[X].number == number)
      {
        if(structure[X].first_info == -1)  /* adding braces */
        { 
          structure[X].first_info = position;
          structure[X].second_info = position;
          break;
        }
      }
      X++;
}
```

Comment: I would point out that in C the indexing starts at 0 not 1 and the end conditions should be `X<100` for an array of dimension 100.

Comment: Is it standard to start the indexing at `0` or is it good practice?

Comment: Indexing **always**  starts at zero, whether you want to read/write the 0th item, it's up to algorithm.

Comment: I wrote my comment, because beginners often make the mistake of declaring an array `int arr[10]` and loop from 1 to 10, when they should loop from 0 to 9. I assume that this is the case with this example and it's worth pointing that out.

Comment: Apologies, I missed your point. For arrays indexing always starts at 0.

Comment: I downvoted you because you give a code-solution without discussing the why/how. The OP doesn't learn from that.

Comment: You changed the behavior of the code both for the range of `X` and the grouping of instructions after the third `if` without any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop construct groups the index variable initialization, loop conditional, and index increment steps of the loop into one statement. So in order to convert a `for` loop into a `while` loop, you just need to unwrap this grouping into effectively three separate statements. In general, you can transform any `for` loop into a `while` loop using the following algorithm. Take a `for` loop like so:

```
for(A;B;C) { /* where A,B,C are valid C statements (e.g., X=0), not variables */
   /* operational code */
}
```

To the following `while` loop using the same statements within the A, B, C placeholders:

```
A;
while(B) {
   /* operational code */
   C;
}
```

With this algorithm, you should be able to convert any `for` loop into a equivalent `while` loop.

Answer (score -2):

I think this one is pretty simple. Maybe I misunderstood your situation, if then forgive me :)

My approach is like this:

```
var X = 1;
while (X<=100)
{
  if(structure[X].number == -1)
  {
    structure[X].number = number;
    structure[X].first_info = position;
    structure[X].second_info = position;
    break;
  }
  if(structure[X].number == number)
  {
    if(structure[X].first_info == -1) 
    structure[X].first_info = position;
    structure[X].second_info = position;
    break;
  }
  X++;
}
```

Comment: What is the `var` in `var X = 1;`?

Comment: You give a code-solution without discussing the why/how. The OP doesn't learn from that.

Answer (score -2):

Existing code can be converted into while as below

```
int x =1;
while(x!=100)
{
    //Your code here 
    x++;
}
```

Comment: What is the `var`?

Comment: var is a type like other types like int, string etc only difference is var identifies it's type based on it's value. Here we have assigned 1 to this variable so var will be int type automatically.

Comment: `var` and `string` are not standard types in C.

Comment: Is it specific to C language? We have these types in C#

Comment: Those are 2 different languages, my friend. In C, there's no dynamic type binding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837972/static-type-binding-vs-dynamic-type-binding

Comment: Yes, I know. I didn't see the tag for this question and thought to be generic. In this case we can use int here.