# Change For Loop into While Loop

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

I'm new to programming and I need to switch this code into a while Loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
   int i,n,sum=0;

   printf("Input number of terms : ");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   printf("\nThe odd numbers are :");
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
     printf("%d ",2*i-1);
     sum+=2*i-1;
   }
   printf("\nThe Sum of odd Natural Number upto %d terms : %d \n",n,sum);
}
```

The question is Write a program in C to display the n terms of odd natural number and their sum

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting "for" loop to "while" loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49211160/converting-for-loop-to-while-loop)

Answer (score 1):

The loop continuation condition stands alone while initialization and incrementation are done separately, before and within the loop, respectively.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() 
{
   int i,n,sum=0;

   printf("Input number of terms : ");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   printf("\nThe odd numbers are :");
   i = sum;
   while(i<=n)
   {
     printf("%d ",2*i-1);
     sum+=2*i-1;
     i++;
   }
   printf("\nThe Sum of odd Natural Number upto %d terms : %d.   
   \n",n,sum);
}
```

You can use a 'do while' loop if you know the first iteration will always take place; the loop continuation condition is evaluated after execution.

```
do {
    ...
} while(i <= n);
```

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop consists of 4 parts:

```
for ( initial_expression; loop_condition; update_expression )
{
    //body
}
```

- `initial_expression` gets executed once, when entering the loop.
- `loop_condition` is checked when entering the loop, and after each iteration
- `update_expression` is executed each iteration. ( NOT at the first entry to loop )
- body is executed each iteration.

Whereas a `while` loop consists of 2 parts:

```
while ( loop_condition )
{
    //body
}
```

In order to make your `while` loop behave as your `for` loop, you need to add other two parts yourself.

```
initial_statement;
while ( loop_condition )
{
    //body
    update_expression;
}
```

This is identical to the previous `for` loop. I recommend you to check flowcharts for `while` and `for` loops to get better understanding of work flow.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (i++<=n) {
  /* whatever */
}
```

will do the job